# 4 level laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have four tables and i want to make a 4 level relationship. My table looks like this:

```
------------|------------|------------|------------|
    City    |  Category  |Subcategory |   Company  |
------------|------------|------------|------------|
     id     |     id     |     id     |     id     |
    name    |    name    |    name    |    name    |
------------|------------|------------|------------|
```

I did something like this:

City.php

```
 public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
```

Category.php

```
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Subcategory::class);
}
```

Subcategory.php

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

But it's not giving the result I need. I have many cities that can have many companies by their category and subcategories. For example I can save city_id, category_id, subcategory_id to company table and get the right companies doing the query:

```
 $company->where('city_id', 1)->where('category_id', 2)->where('subcategory_id', 3)->get();
```

But I think it's not a best practice. I hope somebody helps. Thanks.

The main question is how can i make a normal relationship from this query:

I have many Cities that can has many categories that has many Subcategories and the subcategories i have companies for the specific city->category->subcategory.

For example in **`Company`** model i have **`city_id, category_id, subcategory_id`** and when i'm fetching *categories* for the specific city there will *subcategories* and in *subcategories* will be *`companies`*.
So the query will be something like:

```
App\Company::where('city_id', 1)->where('category_id', 2)->where('subcategory_id, 3)->get();
```

Sorry for bad explanation. I hope you get it...

Comment: I see your table definitions, but no foreign keys in them. Are they missing or implied?

Comment: @apokryfos Now i just did ->belongsToMany() relationship and i have pivot tables for them like category_subcategory.sql, subcategory_categor.sql.

Comment: You could benefit a lot by reading https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships you're currently missing some key aspects to relationships here.

Comment: @apokryfos I read the documentation and saw lot of examples. But can't make it sense( The main problem is that i cant companies for a specific City. For example i have many cities that have same categories and subcategories but for every Country i have different comapnies. Like imagine 4 selects where im picking city then category then subcategory and for the fourth select i'm getting all companies.

Comment: It looks like i need hasManyThrough but can't get the idea how to use it right way

Comment: @apokryfos So if i select the other Country, category and subcategories are the same but companies different

Comment: how do companies relate to categories?

Comment: @apokryfos I have a hasMany relationship subcategory_id in Company table.

Comment: You need to mention all relevant details in the question itself. As it stands now it's unanswerable.